# Bing Images search URL with disabled safe search

Tags: javascript, ajax, bash, search, bing

I'm trying to retrieve the web page content of Bing Images for a specific query.

I'm currently communicating with Bing through the following URL (in case of a sample `foo` search), from `curl` command line tool:

```
curl http://www.bing.com/images/search?q=foo
```

Since the safe search filter is enabled by default, I'd need to disable it.

How can I do that?
I know that direct API access would be preferable, but I need to bypass them and retrieve the entire web page.

I saw that from the web page, the safe search is disabled through Ajax calls.
What URL should I contact to make a search with safe search disabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct solution is to use the query parameter `safeSearch=off`, like

```sh
curl http://www.bing.com/images/search?q=foo&safeSearch=off
```

This is not documented anywhere I could find.

Answer (score 2):

1. Add `&adlt_set=off` to the Bing Search url to close SafeSearch.
2. `&adlt_set=moderate` to filter adult images and videos but not text from your search results.
3. `&adlt_set=Strict` to filter out adult text, images, and videos from your search results.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simply to add `&safesearch=off` to the search URL.

Comment: **Doesn’t work** (anymore?): https://www.bing.com/images/search?q=test&safesearch=off  (Neither with caps: https://www.bing.com/images/search?q=test&safesearch=Off and https://www.bing.com/images/search?q=test&Safesearch=Off and https://www.bing.com/images/search?q=test&SafeSearch=Off.)